Regular Expression to validate a CAGE Code
We need to write a RegEx which can validate a CAGE Code
A CAGE Code is a five (5) position code. The format of the code is

the first and fifth position must be numeric.
The second, third and fourth may be any mixture of alpha/numeric excluding alpha letters I and O.
Case insensitive

We came up with a RegEx cageCode = new RegEx(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$/) which is not properly validating the requirements given.
What could be the possible regEx which could validate the requirements mentioned?

Well, a-z is all-inclusive so make it exclusive of "I and O"

You're trying to match 5 characters which could be either numbers or letters. Try something like this:
^\d(?:(?![ioIO])[A-Za-z\d]){3}\d$

To break it down:

^\d: Will check if the string starts with a number
(?:(?![ioIO])[A-Za-z\d]){3}: To check if there are 3 alphanumeric characters except i/o/I/O
\d$: To validate if the string ends with a number


A simple regex to achive the requirement is:
^\d[A-HJ-NP-Za-hj-np-z\d]{3}\d$

This is explained as:
^        Start of string
\d       A digit
[A-HJ-NP-Za-hj-np-z\d]
         A character clas comprising A to H, or J to N, or P to Z,
         plus the same in lower case, plus digits. This thus omits the  I, i O and o.
{3}      Three of the above characters
\d       A final digit
$        End of string


^(?![IO])[0-9A-HJK-NP-Z]{5}$

you can use tools to verify it
https://www.leiga.com/free-tools/ai-regular-expression-generator

A consolidated list of RegExs to achive the requirement:
function validateCageCode(x: string) {
    const cageCodeRegEx = new RegExp(/^[0-9][A-HJ-NP-Z\d][A-HJ-NP-Z\d][A-HJ-NP-Z\d][0-9]$/i);
    // const cageCodeRegEx = new RegExp(/^[0-9][A-HJ-NP-Za-hj-np-z0-9]{3}[0-9]$/i);
    // const cageCodeRegEx = new RegExp(/^\d(?:(?![ioIO])[A-Za-z\d]){3}\d$/i); 
    // const cageCodeRegEx = new RegExp(/^\d[A-HJ-NP-Za-hj-np-z\d]{3}\d$/i); 
    return cageCodeRegEx.test(x);
}

// Example usage:
console.log(validateCageCode("1ABC2")); // true
console.log(validateCageCode("1A0B2")); // true
console.log(validateCageCode("1AIB2")); // false (contains 'I')
console.log(validateCageCode("1AOB2")); // false (contains 'O')
console.log(validateCageCode("A1234")); // false (first character is not a digit)
console.log(validateCageCode("12345")); // true
console.log(validateCageCode("1def2")); // true
console.log(validateCageCode("1d0e2")); // true
console.log(validateCageCode("1eid2")); // false (contains 'i')
console.log(validateCageCode("1dob2")); // false (contains 'o')
console.log(validateCageCode("x1234")); // false (first character is not a digit)
console.log(validateCageCode("12345")); // true


Done. Thanks for the suggestion
